# can't view design in windows forms during Live Share

Tags: c#

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2022, I started a Live Share session with my friend but he couldn't access the "Design" tab (the main Design of the application).
I've seen some posts about this problem, and they date back to 2019 so I'm not sure if the problem has been dealt with...
I assumed that it has been solved because it has been three years.
anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess they don't allow it. They don't want users to lock it.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/1538